# file_get_html gets an empty page

Tags: simple-html-dom

Im trying to get the content of a certain webpage via file_get_html.

The thing is that I managed to do it before but now it gives me an empty result without any error msg.

```
file_get_contents('http://www.google.com') or die('this is not a valid url');
```

the url is valid. i chekced it by pasting it to my browser.

I tried playing with the user_agent :

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'My-Application/2.5');
```

or even

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.24 (KHTML like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1055.1 Safari/535.24');
```

but nothing..
any suggestions?

Comment: What is the return value of it when you call it?

Answer (score 0):

try **[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)**

It would be something like :

```
$input=file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
$input=htmlspecialchars($input);
echo $input;
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable "allow_url_fopen" in php.ini , the code is fine

Comment: Hi lee, it's allready enabled? other suggestion? it seems that either I can pull anything or I can't pull nothing. could it be that the website is bloking my IP?